# Using same ResultSet for every row inside JSONArray

Tags: java, mysql, sql, json, resultset

I have a java application which keeps data in a database (`MySQL`), and I use `JSON` to transmit data in a proper form. I can fetch and insert data into a `JSONArray`, but whenever the `ResultSet` cursor reaches to the last column of the first row, execution is ended. And I have two rows in the table, `SQL` query is executed successfully.

> I've tried to fix the issue by using many loops, conditions, etc. but the **`Resultset`** inside those loops either returns a **`NullPointer`** or **`SQLSyntaxError`**. I never succeded, so I would appreciate it if you could reply my question.

---

**`The original java class without the loops`**

```
public class JsonSuccessReport {

public JsonSuccessReport() {
}

private Connection connection;
private Statement statement;

public void GenerateSuccessReportAsJson(String idNumber) throws SQLException
{
    String query = "SELECT USERS.idnumber, SUCCESS_REPORT.subject_name, "
            + "SUCCESS_REPORT.hours, SUCCESS_REPORT.midterm, "
            + "SUCCESS_REPORT.`final`, SUCCESS_REPORT.average, "
            + "SUCCESS_REPORT.attandance, SUCCESS_REPORT.semester, "
            + "SUCCESS_REPORT.academic_year "
            + "FROM USERS "
            + "INNER JOIN SUCCESS_REPORT "
            + "ON USERS.iduser=SUCCESS_REPORT.`USERS_iduser` "
            + "WHERE USERS.idnumber=" + idNumber;

    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

        JsonObject jsonResponse = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray data = new JsonArray();


        if (rs.next()) {
            JsonArray row = new JsonArray();
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("subject_name")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("hours")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("midterm")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("final")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("average")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("attandance")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("semester")));
            row.add(new JsonPrimitive(rs.getString("academic_year")));
            data.add(row);
        }

        jsonResponse.add("jsonSuccessReport", data);
        System.out.println(data);

    } finally {
        ConnectionUtility.close(rs);
        ConnectionUtility.close(statement);
        ConnectionUtility.close(connection);
    }}}
```

---

> **`GenerateSuccessReportAsJson("09010102234");`**

```
[["Information Technologies","3","0","0","0","0","spring","2013-2014"]]
```

---

> **`The original SQL syntax and its result`**

```
SELECT USERS.idnumber, SUCCESS_REPORT.subject_name, 
       SUCCESS_REPORT.hours, SUCCESS_REPORT.midterm, 
       SUCCESS_REPORT.`final`, SUCCESS_REPORT.average, 
       SUCCESS_REPORT.attandance, SUCCESS_REPORT.semester, 
       SUCCESS_REPORT.academic_year
FROM USERS INNER JOIN SUCCESS_REPORT ON USERS.iduser=SUCCESS_REPORT.`USERS_iduser` WHERE USERS.idnumber=09010102234;
```

*Executed query*

```
+-------------+--------------------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+
| idnumber    | subject_name             | hours | midterm | final | average | attandance | semester | academic_year |
+-------------+--------------------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+
| 09010102234 | Information Technologies |     3 |       0 | 0     |       0 |          0 | spring   | 2013-2014     |
| 09010102234 | Conflict Management      |     3 |       0 | 0     |       0 |          0 | spring   | 2013-2014     |
+-------------+--------------------------+-------+---------+-------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

> **`What I want to see in result`**

```
[["Information Technologies","3","0","0","0","0","spring","2013-2014"],["","3","0","0","0","0","spring","2013-2014"]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
if (rs.next())
```

to

```
while (rs.next())
```

`next()` moves the resultset cursor and returns `true` if new row is valid. Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)